# How to get the original rotation Quaternion from the Euler in Three.js

Tags: node.js, math, three.js, quaternions, euler-angles

I have an Euler calculated from a rotation Quaternion. I want to store the Euler and then load it somewhere else to calculate the original Quaternion. How can I achieve that?

```
const rot = new THREE.Quaternion(-0.00122, 0.98602, -0.15773, -0.05371);
const {x, y, z} = new THREE.Euler().setFromQuaternion(
        rot,
        'YXZ',
      );
 // How to make rot1 euqal to rot (as close as possible)?
 const rot1 = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(x, y, z));
 console.log(rot); // Quaternion {_x: -0.00122, _y: 0.98602, _z: -0.15773, _w: -0.05371}
 console.log(rot1); // Quaternion {_x: 0.0012199961779640698, _y: -0.9860197701687391, _z: -0.15688998318156033, _w: 0.056116464812051764}
 console.log(rot1.inverse()); // Quaternion {_x: -0.0012199961779640698, _y: 0.9860197701687391, _z: 0.15688998318156033, _w: 0.056116464812051764}
```

Directions are wrong and w error seems a bit big.
Here is the [fiddlejs](https://jsfiddle.net/gongxinheng/jc6t8ndq/21/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two problems here with your script.

1) The Euler rotation axis order 'YXZ' is missing when creatin a quaternion from an Euler angle:

```
const rot1 = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(x, y, z, 'YXZ'));
```

2) Quaternion and Euler angle have different precision. Use a function to get a smaller precision when convertion the Euler angle to Quaternion:

```
 // Update decimal precision
 const decimalPrecision = 100000;
 function updatePrecision(input) {
    return Math.round(input*decimalPrecision) / decimalPrecision;
 }

 const rot1SmallerPrecition = {
    x: -updatePrecision(rot1.x),
    y: -updatePrecision(rot1.y),
    z: -updatePrecision(rot1.z),
 }
```

Here a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/damienleroux/gyprhca8/2/) with corrections

Comment: This is good enough. Thanks Damien. Why does it still need to negate everything to get the original quaternion? Any easier way to get to it if I don't care the precision?

Comment: Quaternion.inverse seems only inverse x, y, z not w